# Versions of Tanaka's SDE

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Consider the following versions:

$$dX_t=x_0+sgn(X_t)dW_t \tag1$$

$$dX_t=x_0+1_{(0,+\infty)}(X_t)dW_t \tag2$$

$$dX_t=x_0+1_{(-\infty,0]}(X_t)dW_t \tag3$$

SDE (1) is a classical example of SDE with no strong solution. SDE (2) has the following strong solution $X_t=x_0+W_{t\wedge \sigma}$, where $\sigma=\inf\{t\ge 0 : x_0+W_t\le 0\}$. However, SDE (3) is not similar to (2), e.g. if $x_0=0$, $X_t=0$ is not a solution of (3). Anyway, is there a solution of SDE (3) in some sense?

---

**Edit**:

It seems that the answer is negative. Set $x_0=0$ and take any twice cont. differentiable function $f$ with $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=0$. Then if $X_t$ is a solution of (3), using Ito formula

\begin{align}
f(X_t)1_{(0,\infty)}(X_t)&=\int_0^t f'(X_s)1_{(0,\infty)}(X_s)1_{(-\infty, 0]}(X_s)dW_s \\
&+\int_0^t f''(X_s)1_{(0,\infty)}(X_s)1_{(-\infty, 0]}(X_s)ds=0,
\end{align}

which means that $X_t\le 0$ for all $t$ a.s. Plugging this into (3) implies that $X_t$ must be equal to $W_t$, which is not nonnegative for all $t$.

Does this make sense? 
Thank's!

Comment: Could you elaborate why $f(X_t) 1_{(0,\infty)}(X_t) = 0$ implies $X_t \geq 0$ for all $t$...?  Isn't it exactly the other way round, i.e. that this implies $X_t \leq 0$? (... because then the indiactor function at the left equals $0$.)

Comment: @saz Sure. Fixed a typo...

Comment: ...then it makes sense. At least to me ;).

Comment: @saz Is it correct to argue that in that case $X_t=W_t$ because $1_{(-\infty,0]}=1$ for all $t$ a.s.?

Comment: I don't see why it should be wrong. If $X_t \leq 0$ a.s., then $1_{(-\infty,0]}(X_t)=0$ a.s.